# Laser alarm circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I have connected all the connections as per the following circuit diagram on a breadboard. When I connect the battery, the buzzer goes off irrespective of resistance of ldr for some time. Then, nothing happens whatsoever be the resistance of the ldr until the battery is reconnected. If connected again... This repeats. Please help.[image]

I have a doubt with connection of RV1
How can I connect my potentiometer(same as in an image) in accordance with the circuit diagram. Can u tell me which one is A,B,C? Which is the one with the arrowhead in the diagram?
[image]

Comment: Have you correctly set RV1? What is the correct operation of the circuit?

Comment: Edited... Buzzer is supposed to go off when the laser pointed at the ldr is obstructed, for a certain time. Then the laser is again restored. It's actually a burglar alarm.

Comment: Re the potentiometer - pins B and C are the ends of the resistance element, and A is the wiper (the connection with the arrowhead).  It should be easy to determine the connections by a visual examination of the pot, or testing with an Ohmmeter.

Comment: Why isn't there a cap on the CV pin?

Comment: No idea.. This is the one I got

Comment: The LED is used to set the POT position.  It should be set so the LED changes when the light beam is broken.  Then the 555 IC is used to turn the buzzer on for a set period.

Comment: Source of diagram should be shown.This diagram appears in many places but [**this is probably the original**](http://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/laser-security-alarm-circuit-diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Source of diagram should be shown.This diagram appears in many places but [**this is probably the original**](http://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/laser-security-alarm-circuit-diagram)

To check operation carry out the following steps.

Circuit may be working from 555 on - it sounds like the input stage is not toggling:

- Disconnect UA1 pin1  to U2 pin 2.

  - Connect a wire to U2 pin2. Call this TP1 (test point 1. )
    Connect TP1 to 5v, then to ground, then to 5v.
    Buzzer should sound for a few second then stop.
    Repeating the %V/ground/5V action should retrigger the buzzer each time.

If that works, reconnect the UA1 pin1  to U2 pin 2 connection, and ...

All voltages are relative to ground unless otherwise stated.

- 1. U8 pin8 etc should be 5V
- 2. U1A pin 3 should vary in voltage as light level on LDR changes.
- 3. U1A pin 2 should vary in voltage as RV1 is adjusted
- 4. Measure and record voltages at U1A pin 3 with LDR fully dark and fully illuminated by LASER. The voltage on U1A pin 2 MUST be able to be adjusted with RV1 to lie within the range of the voltages above.
- Ideally the voltage on U1A pin2 should be able to be adjusted to above and below the range in (3) above.
- 5 Voltage on U1A pin 1 should change state as pin 3 voltages goes from above to below or below to above voltage on pin 2.

If all above works as shown the circuit should now work.